# In NLP using tf-idf how to find the frequency of specific word from the corpus(contaning large numbers of documentation) in python

Tags: python, nlp, tf-idf, n-gram, countvectorizer

How to find the frequency of an individual word from the corpus using Tf-idf. Below is my sample code, now I want to print the frequency of a word. How can I achieve this?

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
corpus = ['This is the first document.',
      'This is the second second document.',
      'And the third one.',
      'Is this the first document?',]
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
X
print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
X.toarray()
vectorizer.vocabulary_.get('document')

print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())

X.toarray()

vectorizer.vocabulary_.get('document')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `vectorizer.vocabulary_` has the count for each word:

```
print(vectorizer.volcabulary_)

{'this': 8,
 'is': 3,
 'the': 6,
 'first': 2,
 'document': 1,
 'second': 5,
 'and': 0,
 'third': 7,
 'one': 4}
```

Calculating word frequency is straightforward then:

```
vocab = vectorizer.vocabulary_
tot = sum(vocab.values())
frequency = {vocab[w]/tot for w in vocab.keys()}
```